# OSX Leopard HID getting simple keyboard input example?

Tags: macos, keyboard, mouse, osx-leopard

I am about to implement simple keyboard and mouse input on osx for my engine. I want to abstract the implementation in more generic c++ classes like Keyboard and Mouse plus appropriate Listeners for portability. Anyways, I came across the Leopard HID Api (http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/technotes/tn2007/tn2187.html#TNTAG9000-SAMPLE_CODE_)which seems to be the right way to go for the osx implementation of these classes. Anyways, the examples of the HID are very complex and I can't really wrap my head around it as fast as I wished I could, so I was wondering if anybody has used it allready to get some basic mouse and keyboard input, or knows about some good examples/resources online.
Or Maybe even a totally different way to go?

thanks

Comment: To be honest, I think this might be way more low level than you need. I'm not familiar with OSX at all, but this looks closer to driver-level code than application-level code.

Comment: well the problem is all the other cocoa implementations I found are bound to an application window and I would like to seperate windowing and keyboard/mouse/etc.

Comment: okay, I just came across this: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html

I think This will allow me to seperate the events from any kind of View or Windowing